# How to reduce the hide-delay of Windows 7 taskbar previews?

Tags: windows-7, windows

When you hover the mouse over a taskbar item in Windows 7, it pops up the thumbnail preview.  When you remove the mouse, there is a short delay and then the thumbnail disappears.  Does anyone know if there is a registry setting to reduce this delay?

I've only found how to change the delay for it to appear, but not to change the time to disappear.

Comment: My preference is to disable it completely using [7 Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker).

Comment: @sblair: I have seen loads of people saying that they disable it, but I can't see how they switch windows effectively...  I tend to have up to 30 windows open at any time though so maybe that's why I like it.  As an aside, why did you remove "thanks" when you edited my post?

Comment: Because of: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/131494). I thought the title could be worded better, so I removed the "thanks" at the same time.

Comment: This website might have the answer you are looking for: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-adjust-taskbar-thumbnail-delay-time-in-windows-7/